# Update two different strings in one column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, I have a simple question here where I want to update my column whenever these two value are used.

```
UPDATE products SET description='YES' WHERE description='PENDING'
```

other than 'PENDING', I also want 'NO' to be included in this query for update.

What can I do? I want it to be updated on any row I update/click, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for st. like this?

```
UPDATE products 
SET description='YES' 
WHERE description IN ('PENDING','NO') AND
      id = 3
```

It sets `description="YES"` to all rows where description is equal to `PENDING` or `NO`.

Comment: Hi, @panther, yeah, it's almost what I want, but it changes all the row. I just want that particular row to change.

Comment: Just add second condition, I updated my answer. For exaple row ID, or st. else what´s is unique for row you want to change.

Comment: What if I want every distinct id to be able to change, not only a single one like declared above? Whenever I click on any of the row, and only that row will change, and others also.

Comment: I don´t know what you want... For changing single row (or more rows using more IDs in query) use my code, if you want to change ALL rows, just leave id=3. Do you want to change multiple lines, which lines? How to define them?

Comment: I want to change one value in the row, without affecting the whole column.   for example, I want pending of that row change into yes, the other data in the column remain the same.

Comment: _one value in the row_ - sure, `description="..."`, _without affecting the whole column_ - the condition defined in WHERE clause. All you need to know is above. If you still don´t know, show me your table, data and what rows should be changed.

Comment: Sorry my friend @pnther, I still don't know and I use the query and it still can't get what I want. OK, here's my table, u can see here, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35009438/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-06%20at%204.17.45%20PM.png , I just want to update the first pending into YES without affecting 2nd pending.

Comment: Ah, so st. like this: `UPDATE products SET description='YES' WHERE description = 'PENDING' ORDER BY pid DESC LIMIT 1`? It takes first one sort by pid.

Comment: hm... but I want it to be any row also I can change the description from pending to yes. When I update more data, I will have more pending, so I will need to update them one by one, not only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
update products
set description = 
case 
when description='PENDING' then 'YES'
else 'NO'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
UPDATE products SET description=if(<Your Condition to set Value YES>,'YES','NO') WHERE description='PENDING'
```

Comment: I want it to be able to update each 'pending' and change it to 'yes' or 'no' for each row, not update all the column data.

Comment: @Confuser.. I have updated answer. What is your condition to set description "Yes" or "NO"

Comment: my condition is different id? is it possible? for different id, set yes to replace the pending. So it won't update the whole column with same pending value.

Comment: What do you mean by different id? Please explain more

Comment: Means, every single row with different id, I'll be able to change it individually, not change "yes" and all became "yes".

Comment: I have posted a new question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803545/mysql-php-update-data-of-each-row