# MYSQL PHP update data of each row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this question which I'm thinking for some time.

I have a table like this shown using php code in browser

```
username  |  price  |  description | 

 a       |  aaa     |   pending | [yes] [no] 
 b       |  bbb     |   yes     | [yes] [no]
 a       |  ccc     |    no     | [yes] [no]
```

only username, price and description are from mysql database.

for the [yes] and [no] is the button post to the query of this. products is my table name

```
 [yes] = UPDATE products SET description='YES' WHERE description='PENDING'
 [no]  = UPDATE products SET description='NO' WHERE description='PENDING'
```

What can I do with my query? I want the yes and no button update only a single row, 
Can I use GROUP BY ? The query I used is totally wrong as it changes all pending into yes whenever I have more than one pending.

Comment: You have a column named [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)? I hope you're using ticks `\`` around it somewhere in your query, which you're not showing.

Comment: `AND title = <your_value>` ?

Comment: I wouldn't use any column other than id to choose a record, I don't know about your specific needs, but titles are usually not unique.

Comment: You're going to have to reformat your graphically-designed question; it's very confusing. Here I thought you had a column named `update`, which probably isn't the case.

Comment: You need to add another column which needs to be unique if you want to achieve what you want.

Comment: `WHERE approval='pending' and username = 'unique_user'` - You have 2 identical usernames `a`'s usernames must/should be unique (*unless you meant a-b-c*), otherwise you could have problems. Plus, I don't see a column called `description`; again, confusing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe he is joining the user table with username = username ?

Comment: @Daan It's a 50/50 split. Something needs to be unique in a table, otherwise, something will go haywire. Email addresses are usually a good bet. Imagine having 2 people with the same?

Comment: @Fred-ii- true that's why he needs to add another column. What table are you assuming this is a request to register?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I clarify the description, I edited the questions query. Hopefully, by just changing the query can solve my question.

Comment: You need to add another column to your query in order to get uniqueness. Plus, how/where are your buttons to activate this?

Comment: @Fred-ii- reread his question [yes][no] are the buttons

Comment: @Daan OP needs uniqueness, which I've already said but haven't gotten feedback. The ball is in his/her court now ;) Having username `a` and username `a` = problem.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii-, actually I depicted a few column to be shown, and the table is actually like this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35009438/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-06%20at%204.17.45%20PM.png, and the [yes] and [no] button just to use to update the value of pending into yes and no, not all pending but only for that row's pending only.

Comment: `UPDATE products SET approval='YES' WHERE description='PENDING' and pid=90` - bingo, unique, and one row updated.

Comment: Now, can I set a range to the pid? for example from pid =0 to pid=1000

Comment: `WHERE pid BETWEEN 0 AND 1000` --- `UPDATE products SET approval='YES' WHERE description='PENDING' and pid BETWEEN 0 AND 1000`

Comment: @Fred-ii- but all will set to 'yes' right? if for others are 'pending'. How to make it set individually yes?

Comment: Sorry, I have work to do, and I can't help you anymore than I already have, my workday awaits. Please ask the people who have given you answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the data, save the id of each object on the "id" HTML attribute. You can do this by setting it to something like id="row-id".

Then, when you update, you just use php to grab the id and you can add it to your query.

```
"UPDATE products SET description='YES' WHERE id=:id"
```

Comment: *"`WHERE id=:id`"* - Assuming OP is using PDO which isn't known.

Comment: We'll make him use it if he isn't!

Answer (score -1):

.Your where statement is not unique.

Try to grab the id off the current row you wanna update.

```
<a href="?update=YES&id=ROW_ID">Yes</a>
<a href="?update=NO&id=ROW_ID">No</a>
```

And then in your sql query you have something like this

```
"UPDATE products SET description='" . $_GET['update'] . "' WHERE id='" . $_GET['id'] . "'"
```

Comment: You're from a JS background, correct? Those `+` need to be `.` dots. `'" + $_GET['update'] + "' WHERE id='" + $_GET['id'] + "'` to `'" . $_GET['update'] . "' WHERE id='" . $_GET['id'] . "'`

Comment: I just wanna give him the basics. But that is true, he need to do some validation before sending those values to the database.